# Is possible to pass data from slot-component to parent in vueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new in VueJS and I'm try to do something like this

I have 3 components, `siderbar` ; `siderbar-item` and `sidebar-drop`

siderbar.vue is a wrapper when you can put `siderbar-item` and `sidebar-drop`, and inside `sidebar-drop` you can put `sidebar-item` too

for example:

```
<sidebar>

    <sidebar-item url="myurl" title="Dashboard" icon="fas fa-tachometer-alt" badge=""></sidebar-item>



    <sidebar-drop title="News" icon="fas fa-tachometer-alt">
        <sidebar-item url="myurl_news" title="News list" icon="fas fa-tachometer-alt" badge=""></sidebar-item>
        <sidebar-item url="myurl_news_add" title="Add News" icon="fas fa-tachometer-alt" badge=""></sidebar-item>
    </sidebar-drop>


    <sidebar-drop title="Categories" icon="fas fa-tachometer-alt">
        <sidebar-item url="myurl_categories" title="Categories List" icon="fas fa-tachometer-alt" badge=""></sidebar-item>
    </sidebar-drop>


</sidebar>
```

sidebar.vue is very simple:

```
<aside>
    <slot></slot>
</aside>
```

sidebar-item.vue

```
<template>
     <ul class="menu-list" >
        <li>
            <a :href="url"  :class="{'is-active': is_active }">
                <span class="icon"><i v-if="icon" :class="icon"></i></span>
                {{ title }}
                <span v-if="badge" class="button badge is-info is-small is-pulled-right "> {{ badge }}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['title', 'url', 'icon', 'badge'],

    data() { 
        return {
            is_active:  this.$current_url === this.url
         } 
    }
}
</script>
```

and sidebar-drop.vue

```
<template>
    <ul class="menu-list" v-if="title">
        <li @click="openMenu"  :class="{'is-open': is_open}">
            <a class="">
                <span v-if="icon" class="icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></span>
                {{ title }}
                <span class="badge is-pulled-right" style=""> <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> </span>
            </a>
            <slot></slot>  
        </li>
    </ul> 
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: ['title', 'icon'],


    data() {
       return {
          is_open: false,
       }
    },

    methods: {
        openMenu(){
            this.is_open = !this.is_open;
        },
    }

}
</script>
```

It works great, but I have a little problem. If you notice, sidebar-item has a data called "is_active", it only put a CSS class that this item is active. Great.

Now I'm trying to get into `sidebar-drop` if a least one of his children has data "is-active" in true, change the `is_open` sidebar-drop parent data to true.

Example: I click "News" item.

- Ul li News is active... works!
- Ul li parent drop is open... don't work

Is possible make that?

Thanks everyone!

**Update:**

I put it in Fiddler to more clear:
https://jsfiddle.net/h35qy2zs/

I do in sidebar-item a random is_active. 
If any child of sidebar-drop (sidebar-item's) data is_active:true, sidebar-drop data is_open is true too.

So, it show in color yellow and open

Result:

[image]

But now, both are closed at refresh page.

Comment: can you add a fiddle or a github link? it will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: Done efrat. I hope it help to understand. Thanks!

Comment: maybe take a look  at what Evan You (the creator of vue.js) has to say about your case: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4332